# Replace Number in RegEx with same Number

Tags: php, regex

```
<?php
function rg($str) {
    $p = '/\[pattern[0-9]\:[a-zA-Z]{3,10}\]/';
    $r = '[pattern[0-9]]';
    $str = preg_replace($p, $r, $str);
    return $str;
}

$s = "[pattern1:reverse] This is my test [pattern1:shift] String for [pattern3:nitro] Reg Ex [pattern2:reverse]";

echo rg($s);
```

The output of this will be

```
[pattern[0-9]] This is my test [pattern[0-9]] String for [pattern[0-9]] Reg Ex [pattern[0-9]]
```

However I am trying to replace the number associated with pattern as it is. So the output would be something like:

```
[pattern1] This is my test [pattern1] String for [pattern3] Reg Ex [pattern2]
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
function rg($str) {
    $p = '/(\[pattern[0-9])\:[a-zA-Z]{3,10}\]/';
    $r = '$1]'; # $1 contains what tou will catch inside the  paranthesis
    $str = preg_replace($p, $r, $str);
    return $str;
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: $r is unused and can be omitted in your example

Comment: nice solution, BUT closing bracket missing though... output:- `[pattern1 This is my test [pattern1 String for [pattern3 Reg Ex [pattern2`

Comment: @JhilkeDai it should be like this `$str = preg_replace($p, '$1]', $str);` (just append the `]`) This answer is almost working with just that little addition. The important thing is the idea of using `$1`.

Comment: @kingKing yes, I did that.... I was about to update the answer or notify Halayem for correction...

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=pattern)(\d+)[^\]]*
```

Try this.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iZ9sO5/4

Comment: thanks, but really didn't understand where shall I put this... your link shows it works, I replaced `$p` with this but it throw error

Comment: the error (or warning) I get is: `PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '(' in file.php line number`